# ¿Como establezco el fragmento predeterminado al iniciar mi aplicacion

Tags: java, android

Estoy usando un BottomNavigationView, tengo 3 fragmentos en un container y al iniciar siempre aparece el fragmento del icono de la izquierda por defecto, quisiera que al iniciar me salga predeterminado otro ítem, el del centro, la verdad no se como hacerlo, agradecia de la ayuda de alguien

```
bottom.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) 
{
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
               case R.id.home:
                    HomeFragment homeFragment =new HomeFragment();

      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, 
      homeFragment)

     .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.searc:
                    SearchFragment searchFragment = new SearchFragment();

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, 
searchFragment)

.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.profile:
                    ProfileFragment profileFragment =new ProfileFragment();

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, 
profileFragment)

.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Veras, la lógica es la siguiente, espero que te pueda servir.
Debes inicializar el fragmento que quieres que sea el que inicie primero en el MainActivity, en el método onCreate()

Lo inicializas de la misma manera que lo estas realizando en el Listener:

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, 
  TU FRAGMENT)

 .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                        .addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

De esta manera aparecerá como principal este fragment.

Espero que sea de ayuda.

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, de  igual forma lo solucione con:    bottom.setSelectedItemId(R.id.home);